# How to make unix timestamp to show time over 24 hours?

Tags: php

I would like to show any give time in hours only.

Example:

Unix timestamp: 169200

Which is equal to 1 day and 23 hours...

But how can I convert this to hours so it shows 47:00:00 (47 hours)?

Thanks

**Edit**: It must show minutes and seconds too ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A unix timestamp is a number of seconds. There are 60 seconds per minute, 60 minutes per hour. So to convert from seconds to hours, divide by `60*60 = 3600`.

If you need the minutes and seconds as well:

```
$timestamp = 169200;

$secs = $timestamp%60;
$mins = floor($timestamp/60);
$hours = floor($mins/60);
$mins = $mins%60;

printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $mins, $secs);
```

http://ideone.com/gFKv2

Comment: Great. But there was a weird number (8) after the seconds. Changing printf to sprintf fixed it :S weird...

Comment: That's probably because I put in an `echo` before `printf`. `printf` returns the length of the printed string, and that is then echoed after print. If you remove the `echo`, `printf` should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours = $timestamp / 3600;
```

You could use `floor()` or `ceil()` to round the hour.